# looping back to beginning of statement using while loop (java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I've been given the task of making a factorial calculator that takes input from 9 to 16 using a while loop. The conditions are that if the user puts in an input that is not 9 to 16 or an int, it should loop back in the beginning and ask for input again.

My code looks like this:

```
Scanner myScanner; 
int x = 1;
int factorial=1; 
int input;
myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("put in an int and i will show you its factorial");
while (true) { 
        input = myScanner.nextInt();
        if (input<9 || input >16) {
                System.out.println("please enter a valid int"); 
        }
        else{
                break; 
        }
}
for (int i=input; i >0; i--) { 
        factorial *= i;
}
```

The problem is that this isn't really using a while loop to go back to the beginning of the code. I'm really just inputting a redundant statement to make it a while loop.

So I guess my question is, how can I make a while loop that goes back to the beginning of the loop if the wrong input is typed in?

Comment: In what way does this *not* go back to the beginning of the loop when you input an invalid int? What behavior is it that you really want to change?

Comment: well i feel like i'm not actually using the while loop to loop back, just inputting it for the sake of putting it there.
what i really want is to loop back to the beginning of the program if the input is wrong, for example:

'9.8'

"please put in a valid input"

'car'

please put in a valid input

'9'

362880

Comment: Have you looked at my answer below? It does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
Scanner myScanner; 
int x = 1;
int factorial=1; 
int input = 0;
myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Put in an integer value between 9 and 16 and I will show you its factorial. Type -1 to exit.");

while (input != -1) { 
    //Try block for handling invalid string inputs
    try {
        input = myScanner.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e){
        input = 0;
    }

    if (input<9 || input >16) {
        System.out.println("please enter a valid int"); 
    }
    else {
        for (int i=input; i >0; i--) { 
            factorial *= i;
            //input = -1; //Optionally end here if that's how things are intended to function
        }    
        System.out.println(factorial);
    }
}
```

Initialize the input with a value (0). And inform the user if they type in a certain value (i.e. -1) the loop ends. Move your for loop in the else block and set the while condition as `input != 1`.

Alternatively, if you want the program to end if the user supplies a valid value, then in the else block, set the input value to -1 manually, or just break out of the loop using the `break` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is to use a boolean value such as

```
boolean validInput = false;
```

and loop until you have valid input. that way you won't try to calculate a value when users enter -1 in the other answer